# how do I "hard-code" check equality for type void?

Tags: flutter, dart, types, void

how do I "hard-code" check equality for type void?

this code runs just fine

```dart
class Foo<T> {
  Type get ofType => T;
  bool isType<S>() => T == S;
}

final _foo = Foo<void>();

void main() {
  print(_foo.ofType);
  print(_foo.isType<void>());
}
```

but this doesn't even compile

```dart
class Foo<T> {
  Type get ofType => T;

  bool isTypeVoid() => T == void;
}

final _foo = Foo<void>();

void main() {
  print(_foo.ofType);
  print(_foo.isTypeVoid());
}
```

```sh
lib/main.dart:3:29:
Error: Expected an identifier, but got 'void'.
  bool isTypeVoid() => T == void;
                            ^^^^
lib/main.dart:3:33:
Error: Expected an identifier, but got ';'.
  bool isTypeVoid() => T == void;
                                ^
lib/main.dart:3:29:
Error: Expected ';' after this.
  bool isTypeVoid() => T == void;
                            ^^^^
lib/main.dart:3:29:
Error: Expected a class member, but got 'void'.
  bool isTypeVoid() => T == void;
                            ^^^^
Error: Compilation failed.
```

I need to hard code the `T == void` in an `assert()` if you are wondering

```dart
assert(T == void)
```

but doesn't work

Comment: Can't you just make it so `Foo<T extends Object>` in your first example if you want to prevent the use of `void`?

Comment: Why void and not null?

Comment: I want to use it in delegate (mixin) that might have return type of void, not null

Comment: @julemand101 I want void to be a possibility

Comment: Strictly speaking, `void` is not a type and cannot be used as a value of return. Read [this article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/the-curious-case-of-void-in-dart-f0535705e529).

Comment: Since the first method works, why don't you use that?  Why do you need `assert(T == void)` instead of `assert(isType<void>())`?  You also could generalize it to a freestanding `bool areTypesSame<S, T>() => S == T;` function.

Comment: isn't hard coded I needed it for assert and if statement
you can check the workaround below

Comment: I don't understand. `isType<void>` is another form of hard-coding it (the `void` part is there in code and isn't specified at runtime).  There shouldn't be anything stopping you from doing `assert(isType<void>())` or `assert(areTypesSame<S, void>())`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like there's no solution for this
here's some references [ [1](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/docs/language/informal/generalized-void.md#discussion), [2](https://spec.dart.dev/DartLangSpecDraft.pdf) (pages 216-217) ]

as for this is an answer, but not a solution
I can offer a `nonsense` workaround

```dart
class Nonsense<T> {
  const Nonsense();
  Type call() => T;
}

const _voidType = Nonsense<void>();

class Foo<T> {
  Type get ofType => T;
  bool isTypeVoid() => T == _voidType();
}

final _foo = Foo<void>();

void main() {
  print(_foo.ofType);
  print(_foo.isTypeVoid());
}
```

thanks to calamity on [discord](https://discord.gg/N7Yshp4) for the guidance